# Problem with pdf attachment sent by mac mail

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, email

I use Mac Mail. Sometimes it happens, that when I attach (drag and drop) a pdf file to a new e-mail message it doesn't show on other computer (PC). Is there a problem on my side? Or is it a matter of the way files are being attached?

Thanks

Comment: Which email client are you using on the PC? What type of account are you sending from on the Mac and receiving to on the PC? (Gmail, iCloud, Outlook, etc). Which versions of the operating systems are you running on your computers?

Comment: On PC it's usually Outlook, but my friend told me he didn't see pdf attachment on his iPhone (sent from Mac Mail). Very strange.